# How to Link mesh to a specific bone from another mesh?

Tags: mesh, armature

I have a hand holding a manipulator.
I want it to stay in the moving hand. Parenting and constraints don't work.
Can i link this manipulator to the bone "wrist.R" from the hand?
I tried to link manipulator to the whole lady's armature and then deleted all extra groups, but it didn't work too.
May be you see another solution?
Thank you.
[image: Manipulator in a hand(armature)]

Comment: you need to select the object, shift select the armature, switch it to Pose mode, select the bon you want and Ctrl P > Bone. You can also do the opposite: parent the hand bone to the object with a Child Of constraint so that it's the object that will make the hand move, it can be more convenient sometimes

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i need. I didn't know i can switch to Pose mode with both objects selected. ) Live and learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the object in *Object* mode, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the bone you want and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>P</kbd> → *Bone*. You can also do the opposite: parent the hand bone to the object with a *Child Of* constraint so that it's the object that will make the hand move, it can be more convenient sometimes