# Using a sphere as a head for a rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

I am not entirely new to Blender but i am a bit new to rigging models. How can you rig a simple sphere mesh to the head bone of a rig?

Comment: maybe check my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240741/how-to-link-mesh-to-a-specific-bone-from-another-mesh?noredirect=1#comment408897_240741

Answer (score 1):

- In *object* mode, select the sphere with the left mouse button.
- Then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the rig with the left mouse button.
- Put the rig in *Pose* mode by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Select the head bone with the left mouse button.
- Finally type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>P</kbd> and select *bone* from the menu that pops up.

Comment: Yep that seemed to work perfectly i really do appreciate your help.